# Set Pandas Value from an Index to an Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to set value of 'D' from index 3-7 as 0, this is the code I have I'm getting a error.

```
df.iloc[3:7, 'D'] = 0
```

I also tried:

```
df.iloc[3:7]['D'] = 0
```

```
     A    B      C  D
0  foo  one  small  1
1  foo  one  large  2
2  foo  one  large  2
3  foo  two  small  3
4  foo  two  small  3
5  bar  one  large  4
6  bar  one  small  5
7  bar  two  small  6
8  bar  two  large  7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `df.loc[df.index[3:7], "D"] = 0`

**EDIT:** i think this will work! But make sure your index is set as index.

```
mask = (df.index >=3) & (df.index <=7)

df.loc[mask, "D"] = 0
```

P. S. : i had a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63413614/11885185) today... It s night in Europe, I will check tomorrow but maybe it helps you earlier!

Comment: Nope, still get ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[3:7, 'D'] = 0
```

The `.iloc` requires you to use the integer position of the column. `.loc` allows you to call it by name.

Comment: Note that `df.loc[3:7]` includes the row with index=7 while `df.iloc[3:7]` does not in this case

Answer (score 1):

Try Using `df.iloc[3:8, 3] = 0` because as you are using .iloc it takes only numbers/position so 3 here is column position starting from 0